# Airflow: download file before send email with EmailOperator

Tags: email, airflow, operators, samba

I have Airflow DAG, where function **_query** executes query in Hive and saves result in network folder with SambaHook.

```
#...
def _query(query_params_callable: Callable, params: Mapping[str, Any], sql, file, **context):
    query_params = query_params_callable(**params)

    smb_hook = SambaHook(samba_conn_id=conn_id_samba)

    with smb_hook.open_file(path=sql, mode='r', share_access='r') as sql_file:
        sql_query = sql_file.read().replace('$', '').format(**query_params)

    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.xlsx', delete=False).name
    hook = HiveServer2Hook(hiveserver2_conn_id=conn_id_hive)
    df = hook.get_pandas_df(f"""{sql_query}""")
    df.to_excel(temp_file, index=False, header=[col.split(".")[1] for col in df.columns])

    file_path = file.format(**query_params)
    smb_hook.push_from_local(file_path, temp_file)

    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    task_instance.xcom_push(key='rows_count', value=len(df))
    task_instance.xcom_push(key='file_path', value=file_path)

#...
def generate_dag(dag_id, dag_settings, run_type):
    with DAG(
            dag_id=f'fr_alm_{dag_id}_{run_type}',
            tags=['fusion', 'hive', 'excel', 'fr_alm_hive_to_excel', 'reports', 'generate'],
            start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(10),
            schedule_interval=dag_settings['schedule'],
            render_template_as_native_obj=True,
            params={
                'report_date': None
            }
    ) as dag:
        start = EmptyOperator(task_id='start')

        task_query = PythonOperator(
            task_id='query',
            python_callable=_query,
            queue=airflow_queue_hadoop,
            op_kwargs={
                'query_params_callable': types[run_type]['callable'],
                'params': {
                    'report_date': '{{ params.report_date }}',
                    'ds': '{{ ds }}',
                    'delay': dag_settings['delay'],
                },
                'sql': dag_settings['sql'],
                'file': dag_settings['file'],
            },
            provide_context=True
        )

        task_email = EmailOperator(
            task_id='email',
            on_execute_callback=email_on_execute_callback
        )

        end = EmptyOperator(task_id='end')

        start >> task_query >> end
#...
```

My goal after **task_query** to execute **EmailOperator**, but before that I need to download file with Samba authorization to local file system that node where EmailOperator is executed.

How can I do this?

I think about a few ways:

1. To use pre_execute - I'm not sure that it works on the same node where EmailOperator is executed.
2. To use on_execute_callback - the same as first
3. To write my own SambaToEmailOperator.

What do you think about possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The pre_execute method is a callback that runs before a task is executed, whereas the actual task runs during the execute method.

therfore, you can write on pre_execute code that copy the file to a temp dir in the node and then email it.

another option (if possible) its to upload the file to S3 (or similar) and then download it or even presigned (url) instead of a file.